# How do I develop a web app for Nokia 6230i?

Tags: java, mobile, nokia

Is there a way to make an app for Nokia 6230i? I cant find info about this.
I want to make, receive simplest http requests

I saw, that all apps on the internet are .jar, so can i use java for it? If yes, how?

Comment: Wasn't phone app development back in those days mostly done using [J2ME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Micro_Edition)? So look up what the available J2ME classes are for HTTP requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "developing way" that I think you're searching for is [J2ME](https://netbeans.org/kb/74/javame/quickstart.html) that is the technology of you can use to make apps for java devices, you can start from there and see if you can implement an web app

Comment: Thanks! I think this is what I was looking for!